# 2 GPUs (for multi-monitor setup)

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card, amd-radeon

I have a machine to which I need to connect a second monitor. This machine currently hosts a ATI Radeon HD 4770 with two DVI adapters. The second monitor to be hooked to this machine is a VGA monitor.

Until I find a DVI->VGA adpater, I'm thinking installing a second graphics card which does have a VGA adapter, an NVidia card.

- Can I successfully run both AMD and
  NVidia cards on this machine?
- Any specifics I must be aware of,
  like how to ensure the ATI card to be
  the main card?

Operating system is Windows 7

Comment: Surely buying a good DVI monitor would be a much better choice than a whole new graphics card? (Unless you're a gamer, but even then, your 4770 is more than capable)

Comment: This is for a second machine. I do not wish to send money with it when I have spare equipment put aside :) The DVI->VGA Adapter is where I will spend money, but I live in a rural area and my local supplier will only get me one next week. I was thinking of a temporary solution.

Comment: oooooh, right, you actually have the second card? That's ok, then.

Comment: You'll spend half that time installing, configuring and then uninstalling the second card.  Not worth the trouble IMHO.

Comment: Ok. thanks folks. Just installed the card and it's working ok. Just need to make sure the second card is not on the first PCIe  slot. With windows 7, so far so good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what operating system you are going to use. I think this is possible in XP however I know for a fact that you cannot in Vista and I remember hearing that they are going to re-enable it in Windows 7, however I have not heard about it for ages or had a chance to test it.

I would say get an adapter quick - you can get them for next to nothing (<£3 inc shipping on eBay) and will do the job without you needing to tinker with your system.

Comment: good point. forgot to mention the operating system. fixed

Answer (score 1):

Yes *but*...

It's less trouble to find an adapter. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

For a while, I used an NVidia PCIe card and some old PCI card simultaneously in Vista.  Worked fine.  The old card was either some old Radeon or an NVidia Riva TNT (probably the latter).

Like Chris Nava said, it's probably less trouble to find, borrow, or buy an adapter.